# Rewrite tf.Session into tf.Estimator API

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-tpu

I have some code which was written with the tf.Session low level API and since I want to use it on a TPU I should rewrite it into tf.Estimator API best, since there is a TPUEstimator class for the TPU acceleration.

Is there a standard way to do this or a guide on how to approach that?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good initial guide can be found here:

https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/using-estimator-api

and more detail in the "TPU Estimator" section on this page:

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_tpu

If you have further questions after reading these docs and the other docs to which they link, please follow up by asking your more detailed questions and tagging them with the google-cloud-tpu tag.